# Error: The data connection uses Windows Authentication and user credentials could not be delegated

Tags: excel-services, excel-online

Environment: SharePoint 2016 (On-prem) with on-prem Office Online

When users attempt to navigate to an Excel file with an embedded datasource, they receive the following error:
The data connection uses Windows Authentication and user credentials could not be delegated.

[image: External Data Refresh Failed]

This error does not occur on all Excel files (all the Excel files in the particular SharePoint site have externally accessing datasources) and opening the file locally in Excel works fine.

The Excel files (working and not working through the browser) have not changed for several years (previously on SharePoint 2013) and the only major change in the past year was changing from NTLM to Kerberos (beginning of the year) and users assured me their reports were working fine after the upgrade.  All the sharepoint servers in the farm have the claims service running and all the Excel files have the same connection configuration.

[image: DataSource Connection Info]

Nothing meaningful/different between different Excel files (ex. a 'broken' file vs. a working file) in SharePoint's ULS logs.

Event log error on the Office online server is:

Credential delegation failed because Excel Services Application was unable to obtain a Windows Identity.

Again, the 'Claims to Windows Token Service' is running on all servers in the farm (logging in as 'Local System') and all running on a single domain+forest.

Any suggestions/workarounds to resolve the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you gone through https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/configure-excel-online-data-refresh-by-using-external-data-connections-in-office?

Comment: @TrevorSeward Thank you for the reply.  Yes, that generated a different error.